# trying to do teatascontent but getting error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to use `TREATASCONTENT()` but getting error. As i want to use the data to control the dynamic module.

Pulling the data that drives the content i want:

```
Set @content1 = content1
```

Setting the content area:

```
SET @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\@content1")
```

Pulling through the content block from above:

```
%%=TREATASCONTENT(@contentblock1)=%%
```

Error:

> Content Area "My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\@content1"
>   could not be found.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `concat()` function to ensure it will be evaluated as a variable, not a literal.  Something like this:

```
%%[
    set @basePath = "My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\"  
    set @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName(concat(@basePath,@content1))
]%%
```